How to use 'muraster' to rasterize a multipage PDF?
As far as I know, there are at least two ways to convert PDF to images using MuPDF:
mutool convert -O resolution=300 -o output%03d.png input.pdf

And:
mutool draw -r 300 -o output%03d.png input.pdf

It seems there is a third way, using muraster.
But what I don't understand is how to use it so that it will convert all the pages and not a single one.
According to the docs, the syntax is muraster [options] file [pages], where [pages] is a comma separated list of page numbers and ranges.
But when I use it as muraster -o output.png input.pdf 1-5 or muraster -o output%d.png input.pdf 1-5, it creates just a single image, which is page 1, and that's it. How is it possible?

Muraster does not produce PNG see the listed formats under -F

Command Line Options
muraster [options] file [pages]
[options]


-F format
The output format (default inferred from output file name), e.g. pam, pbm, pgm, pkm, ppm.

What it does is default to a pbm but even that seems not to use numbers in recent releases so convert worked in versions 23 & 24

But %d does not work with recent muraster versions ?
C:\Users\lez\Downloads\Apps\PDF\mupdf\1.24>muraster -o output%d.ppm input.pdf 1-5

C:\Users\lez\Downloads\Apps\PDF\mupdf\1.24>dir *.ppm
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is EC46-77F1

 Directory of C:\Users\lez\Downloads\Apps\PDF\mupdf\1.24

2024-08-07  11:06       100,690,647 output%d.ppm

You can use a for loop for sequential numbers.
@for /L %c in (1,1,5) do muraster -o output%c.ppm input.pdf %c 2>nul

mupdf\1.24>muraster -o output1.ppm input.pdf 1  2>nul

mupdf\1.24>muraster -o output2.ppm input.pdf 2  2>nul

mupdf\1.24>muraster -o output3.ppm input.pdf 3  2>nul

mupdf\1.24>muraster -o output4.ppm input.pdf 4  2>nul

mupdf\1.24>muraster -o output5.ppm input.pdf 5  2>nul

mupdf\1.24>dir /b o*.ppm
output1.ppm
output2.ppm
output3.ppm
output4.ppm
output5.ppm


please do not post pictures of text ... post the text instead
